# Why we should use uppercaseStringWithLocale of NSString to get correct uppercase string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, unicode

I have a very simple task: from server I get `UTF-8` string as byte array and I need to show all symbols from this string in upper case. From this string you can get really any symbol of unicode table.

I know how to do it in a line of code:

```
NSString* upperStr = [[NSString stringWithCString:utf8str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] uppercaseString];
```

And seems to me it works with all symbols which I have checked. But I don't understand: why we need method **uppercaseStringWithLocale**? When we work with unicode each symbol has unique place in unicode table and we can easily find does it have upper/lower case representation. What trouble I might have if I use `uppercaseString` instead `uppercaseStringWithLocale`?

Comment: In certain regions of the world apparently there's a difference in what character is considered "upper case" of what.  Generally if you're dealing with European languages `uppercaseString` should work fine (though I suppose there's some chance of a problem with, say, German).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs say:

> The following methods perform localized case mappings based on the
>   locale specified. Passing nil indicates the canonical mapping.  For
>   the user preference locale setting, specify +[NSLocale currentLocale].

Assumedly in some locales the mapping from lowercase to uppercase changes even within a character set. I'm not an expert in every language around the globe, but the people who wrote these methods are, so I use 'em.

Comment: Seems you are right. But the worst in current situation is when you are working with unicode as a byte array - you are to able to determine what local you should use with this byte array.

Comment: If you don't know the locale then certainly the generic method is the one to call.

Answer (score 21):

Uppercasing is locale-dependent. For example, the uppercase version of "i" is "I" in English, but "İ" in Turkish. If you always apply English rules, uppercasing of Turkish words will end up wrong.